# Deserializing from JSON to custom object using ObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

I have a problem deserializing JSON data to a custom object using ObjectMapper.

The structure is like this:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "payload": [
    {
      "details": {
        "id": "7758931",
        "description": "A description",
...
```

My code:

```
struct MyObject : Mappable
    {
        var message : String
        var payload : [MyDetail]?

        init(map: Mapper) throws
        {
            try message = map.from("message")
            payload = map.optionalFrom("payload") ?? nil
        }
    }

struct MyDetail : Mappable
{
    var detailId : String
    var descriptionDetail : String

    init(map: Mapper) throws
    {
        try detailId = map.from("id")
        try descriptionDetail = map.from("description")
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not correct since there is dictionary with a key details to parse...

Anyone have an idea how I can parse this?

Comment: you miss `details` namespace

Answer (score 1):

You need a container object that wraps the details since it's nested under the `details` key, like this:

```
struct MyObject : Mappable {
    var message : String
    var payload : [MyDetailContainer]?

    init(map: Mapper) throws {
        try message = map.from("message")
        payload = map.optionalFrom("payload") ?? nil
    }
}

struct MyDetailContainer : Mappable {
    var details: MyDetail

    init(map: Mapper) throws {
        try details = map.from("details")
    }
}

struct MyDetail : Mappable {
    var detailId : String
    var descriptionDetail : String

    init(map: Mapper) throws
    {
        try detailId = map.from("id")
        try descriptionDetail = map.from("description")
    }
}
```

assuming that the json goes on like this like this:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "payload": [
    {
      "details": {
        "id": "7758931",
        "description": "A description"
      },
    },
    {
      "details": {
        "id": "7758932",
        "description": "Description #2"
...
```

Comment: Thanks....if for some reason for example description is nil? all the details object returns nil ...how I can handle this?

Comment: changing the `descriptionDetail` field to an optional `String?` and mapping it with `try descriptionDetail = map.optionalFrom("description")` should do the trick